# How to read Cordova Call History on ios?

Tags: ios, cordova, logging, call

How do I access the call log on iphone with cordova?

The only plugin is for android ( https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin )

Comment: You can get the call history following this tutorial https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/. but your app won't be approved, apple doesn't want you to get the call history inside your app

Comment: the tutorial is too old.. no support for ios9 :(

Comment: Last comment says "afer the ios8,the callHistory is in private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata", should work if you use that url